# Facebook4J Friends Album Photos

Tags: java, facebook, processing

I am using Facebook4J with Processing/Java and I am trying to extract information of friends' photos. I have used the code a few months ago, and it was working fine, but now it returns all fields in null.
Can someone help with this issue? Here is how I used to extract the photos:

```
  User fbUser = facebook.getUser(userID);
  ResponseList<Album> albums = facebook.getAlbums(userID);
  String targetAlbumId = "";
  imgArray = new ArrayList<PImage>();

  for (Album album : albums) {
    //Get the album ID if it matches the string
    if (album.getName().equals("Cover Photos")) {
      targetAlbumId = album.getId();
      break;
    }
  }

  //Get all the photos that correspond to that Album ID
  //Create a string arraylist to store all the photo ID names
  ResponseList<Photo> photos = facebook.getAlbumPhotos(targetAlbumId);
  ArrayList<String> getPhotoId = new ArrayList<String>();

  //Get all photos in high quality. Create an arraylist of all the photos,
  //and an arraylist of all the photo IDs (to use later for getting their likes)
  for (Photo photo : photos) {  
    URL highQuality = photo.getImages().get(0).getSource();
    imgArray.add(loadImage(highQuality.toString()));
    getPhotoId.add(photo.getId());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer access friends photos when your app is using Graph API v2.0 or higher.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

> All `friends_*` permissions have been removed.

Comment: Is there any alternative to get access to this information (friends' photos)? Because it doesn't make sense to have access using Facebook but not to been able to do this through the API